# wrong mysql query syntax

Tags: mysql

if for example this query returns a table name called "invoice" :

select table_name
from Table1
where table_ID = 2

how can I put this query inside a bigger one ?

So instead of :

insert into invoice
values (1,1,1)

I want to write :

insert into 
(select table_name
from Table1
where table_ID = 2)
values (1,1,1)

but this gives an error, can anyone tell me the right syntax 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace a table name with a subquery. It's not possible to do what you want in a SQL query.

If your RDBMS supports stored procedures, you can write one which produces a SQL query from a string using the results of your `SELECT` query as part of that string, then execute it.